# what ever happened to the dev.meta site?

Tags: discussion, api

I used to be a member but I guess my account got deleted? I'm sure the pass has changed but I can't get in for the life of me.

Answer (score 2):

dev.meta is part of our dev tier (shocking, I know).  It is not generally accessible.

During the API [private beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/) it was re-purposed for a short time.  [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) replaced it when the [public beta started](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/), and continues to be our dedicated API site.